# Laravel:file extension validation

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.2 ,i use image rule to validate images uploaded by user,which requires php_fileinfo extension to be installed ,but is there a way to validate images only for there extensions like .png,.jpg etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mimes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimetypes)

```
'photo' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the mime type to your validation like you would add any other rule:

```
$rules = [
    'image' => 'required|image|mimes:gif,png'
];
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-mimes

Comment: it should be mimes no mime

Comment: Changed it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

yes you can by using `mimes` validation [rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-mimes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$validator = Validator::make(
  [
     'file'      => $request->file,
     'extension' => strtolower($request->file>getClientOriginalExtension()),
  ],

  [
     'file'          => 'required',
     'extension'      =>'required|in:txt',
  ]
);
```